# Edit a bootable ISO in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, iso

I have been given an ISO, which is a WindowsPE image with some extra bits. I need to add some files to it. It still needs to be bootable.

I tried isomaster, which works great, mostly, but doesn't show long filenames, and breaks (ALL!) long filenames if I edit it. xorriso does the same (I tried "-readfs any,norock, nojoliet, ecma119).

If I mount the ISO (in Ubuntu), it shows long filenames fine.

Xorriso also warns: "Found hidden El-Torito image. Its size could not be figured out, so image modify or boot image patching may lead to bad results."

How can I add files to this ISO?

Comment: xorriso 1.4.6, isomaster 1.3.13-1, both from Apt.

Answer (score 2):

xorriso command

```
-boot_image "any" "keep"
```

before command `-dev` might keep the ISO bootable. It depends on what
boot equipment is present.
A big obstacle for multi-session might be the presence of a UDF filesystem.
I don't have bootable MS-Windows ISOs. So i cannot make experiments.

Command `-read_fs "norock,nojoliet"` before `-dev` prevents loading of
long names from ISO 9660 Rock Ridge tree or from Joliet tree.
I assume Microsoft does not write our Rock Ridge but only its own Joliet.
Advise: Omit `-read_fs` and let xorriso decide what tree to load.

To list all loaded filenames without burning

```
xorriso -indev $the_iso -find / -- 2>&1 | less
```

Update:

I was able to find `Win10_1607_English_x64.iso`. It is an UDF with a
small ISO 9660 tree that only has a file `/README.TXT`. You can see it if
you mount explicitly `-t iso9660` (auto default is `-t udf`).
The text says:

```
This disc contains a "UDF" file system and requires an operating system
that supports the ISO-13346 "UDF" file system specification.
```

The image contains an El Torito catalog with references to two boot images.
One for BIOS, one for EFI which xorriso could keep. But given the fact that 
the payload is in the UDF tree only, there is no use for xorriso's ISO 9660
multi-session capabilities.

Comment: I *DO* want the long filenames - xorriso and isomaster seem to work fine with long filenames on most ISOs, but not on this one.

Comment: I understand your goal (and frustration). But at least the Win10 ".iso" which i found is not offering its files as ISO 9600 filesystem but rather as its (may i say "annoying" ?) dedicated successor UDF (aka ISO-13346). The boot entry points are like in ISO 9660, but superblock and directory tree are not. I am not aware of any UDF multi-session tool in GNU/Linux. (mkisofs does single session UDF for video.)

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use Imgburn in WINE. I have tried it myself and I have yet to run across a bug. (At least in Wine 1.6) Note that if you do end up getting Imgburn, **DO NOT** run the default installer, as it comes bundled with adware. Instead, [use 7-zip to open the installer EXE and extract the actual program.](http://www.cdrlabs.com/forums/imgburn-longer-safe-install-t25987.html#p179705) Just FYI - the actual program is completely legitimate and safe. It's just that the installer it's bundled with uses *OPENCANDY*.

Once you have Imgburn up and running, you'll find it to be a very powerful program.

You will need to mount the ISO to the file system and extract the contents (note that you do not use Imgburn for that part), and then copy the contents of the ISO into a folder of your choice. Once that's done, you can modify whatever files you need to. After you've done that, you can use Imgburn to rebuild it into an ISO. You'll need to specify the boot sector file as the `etfsboot.com` file found inside the ISO:

[image]